# Which of the following is NOT true? please see the options listed below.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a.  The union of two countable sets is countable.
b.  A subset of a countable set is countable.
c.  If A is an uncountable set, and B is countable, then A - B is uncountable.
d.  The cardinality of the integers is greater than the cardinality of the even integers.

I am thinking d. but not 100%. Can you please give me your much needed input. Thank you.

Comment: d. is the one!!

Answer (score 1):

For example, thinking of (d), check the following map

$$\Bbb N\to 2\Bbb N\;\;,\;\;n\mapsto 2n$$

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed d. To see why it would probably be the easiest to just prove that the two sets have the same cardinality by simply finding a bijection between them. The obvious one is $x\mapsto 2x$.

Another more intuitive approach would be to prove that both sets have the same cardinality as the natural numbers by writing both sets as lists.  First the integers:
$$\{0,1,-1,2,-2,\dots\}.$$

And then the even integers:
$$\{0,2,-2,4,-4,\dots\}.$$